# FLUID ViewHelper form in new window

Tags: forms, typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.1.x

I would like to add the target attribute to a FLUID form, so that after submitting the form, a new window is created.
This does not work, and produces an error:

```
<f:form target="_blank" action="..." name="..." id="..." pageUid="..." controller="..."></f:form>
```

Any ideas on how to make the  to open in a new window?

I use TYPO3 6.2beta5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the `f:form` ViewHelper inherits from the `AbstractTagBasedViewHelper`, it shares the same allowed attributes.

The [fluid documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/stable/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartV/FluidViewHelperReference.html#f-form) inside the TYPO3 Flow documentation shows you all allowed attributes.

To answer your question, the correct way to use it would be:

`<f:form additionalAttributes="{target:'_blank'}">FORMCONTENT</f:form>`

Note that the `additionalAttributes` argument is an array. If you were to add more than 1 custom attribute, you would do it like that:

`<f:form additionalAttributes="{target:'_blank', data-validate: 'foo'}">FORMCONTENT</f:form>`

**EDIT**

The `AbstractTagBasedViewHelper` changed, so the answer as of today for **TYPO3 CMS v7** would be: There's an attribute `data` for that which takes an array of keys and values.

`<f:form data="{foo: 'bar', validate: 'baz'}" ....>
  FORMCONTENT
</f:form>`

Comment: I just came across the documentation, and found the same part. I just looked at the form ViewHelper and not the AbstractTagBasedViewHelper. Thanks for helping me out.